# Automl SDK code with file location from bigquery but having issue while predicting

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, sdk, google-cloud-automl, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I was creating a model using GCP automl sdk module in AI Platform (using bigquery table as input for training and predicting) and predicting using batch_prediction. The issue is that the code runs fine but the output table of predictions is empty and error table has all series from prediction dataframe and addition column stating error code 3 and error is "The time series has no values to predict. The time series has been excluded from predictions.".

Code which I have used for model training:

```
job = aiplatform.AutoMLForecastingTrainingJob(
    display_name='train-sdk-automl_tst1',
    optimization_objective='minimize-mae',    
    column_transformations=[
        {"timestamp": {"column_name": "Date"}},
        {"numeric": {"column_name": "Price"}},
        {"numeric": {"column_name": "Grammage"}},
        {"numeric": {"column_name": "apparentTemperatureMax"}},
        {"numeric": {"column_name": "apparentTemperatureMin"}},
        {"numeric": {"column_name": "Consumer_promo"}},
        {"numeric": {"column_name": "Promo_Value"}},
        {"numeric": {"column_name": "Trade_Promotion"}},
        {"numeric": {"column_name": "Holiday"}},
        {"numeric": {"column_name": "Sales"}},
    ]
)

# This will take around an hour to run
my_model = job.run(
    dataset=ds,
    target_column='Sales',
    time_column='Date',
    time_series_identifier_column='SKU',
    available_at_forecast_columns=['Date', 'Price','Grammage'
                                   ,'apparentTemperatureMax','apparentTemperatureMin','Consumer_promo',
                                   "Promo_Value","Trade_Promotion","Holiday"],
    unavailable_at_forecast_columns=['Sales'],
    forecast_horizon=21.0,
    data_granularity_unit='week',
    data_granularity_count=1,
    weight_column=None,
    budget_milli_node_hours=1000,
    model_display_name='sdk_tsting_bq-forecast-model', 
    predefined_split_column_name=None
)
```

Code for predictions:

```
BATCH_PREDICT_SOURCE = 'bq://acn-intelligent-supply-chain.scoa_ml_forecast_tool.test_data_sdk1'
BATCH_PREDICT_DESTINATION_PREFIX = 'bq://acn-intelligent-supply-chain.scoa_ml_forecast_tool' 
my_model.batch_predict(
   bigquery_source=BATCH_PREDICT_SOURCE,
   instances_format='bigquery',
   bigquery_destination_prefix = BATCH_PREDICT_DESTINATION_PREFIX,
   predictions_format='bigquery',
   job_display_name='predict_sdk_tst')
```

Please suggest what might be going wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the BQ table used for batch prediction needs to have NULL values in the target (e.g. 'Sales') column.  Give that a try if you're not already doing so and see if that helps.